# Can anyone help me with this kernel panic? (IMMEDIATE ungraceful shut down on "restart")

Tags: mac, macos, kernel-panic, shutdown

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance! :)

(OS version is 10.11.0 - I can't upgrade to 10.11.1 without a graceful restart. ouch.)

### Panic Report

```
Anonymous UUID: <snip>



Mon Nov 9 18:48:26 2015



*** Panic Report ***

panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff800bcb47df): "(default pager): [KERNEL]: default memory manager"@/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-3247.1.106/osfmk/default_pager/default_pager.c:421

Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address

0xffffff83b0cdbdb0 : 0xffffff800bce5357
0xffffff83b0cdbe30 : 0xffffff800bcb47df
0xffffff83b0cdbe60 : 0xffffff800bcb462b
0xffffff83b0cdbe80 : 0xffffff800bd45aa1
0xffffff83b0cdbef0 : 0xffffff800c226234
0xffffff83b0cdbf10 : 0xffffff800bdc135a
0xffffff83b0cdbfb0 : 0xffffff800bdf48b6



BSD process name corresponding to current thread: logind

Boot args: vm_compressor=1



Mac OS version:

15A282a



Kernel version:

Darwin Kernel Version 15.0.0: Wed Aug 26 16:57:32 PDT 2015; root:xnu-3247.1.106~1/RELEASE_X86_64

Kernel UUID: 37BC582F-8BF4-3F65-AFBB-ECF792060C68
Kernel slide: 0x000000000ba00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff800bc00000
__HIB text base: 0xffffff800bb00000
System model name: iMac12,2 (Mac-942B59F58194171B)


System uptime in nanoseconds: 357455352557945
last loaded kext at 265840067083946: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub 900.4.1 (addr 0xffffff7f8ef7f000, size 12288)
last unloaded kext at 265900098735706: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub 900.4.1 (addr 0xffffff7f8ef7f000, size 12288)

loaded kexts:
com.viscosityvpn.Viscosity.tun 1.0
com.viscosityvpn.Viscosity.tap 1.0
com.logmein.hamachi 1.0
com.Cycling74.driver.Soundflower 2
com.karios.driver.DuetDisplay 1
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch 90.3
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor 1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AGPM 110.20.19
com.apple.filesystems.autofs 3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager 4.4.0f4
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog 1
com.pple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver 124
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver 272.50
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA 272.50
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient 3.6.1
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry 1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
com.apple.kext.AMDFramebuffer 1.3.6
com.apple.AMDRadeonX3000 1.3.6
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X 7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD3000Graphics 10.0.0
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin 1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.4.0f4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.8.1
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC 3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU 208
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC 1.70
com.apple.kext.AMD6000Controller 1.3.6
com.apple.driver.AppleHV 1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSNBGraphicsFB 10.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.0.8
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl 1.2.13
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBStorageCoexistentDriver 3.7.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 3.7.1
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient 3.7.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController 327.5
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.BootCache 37
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage 2.8.0
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Atheros40 700.74.5
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet 10.1.11
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI 5.5.2
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort 3.1.5
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCIPCI 1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC 2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons 4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET 1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS 2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC 4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC 1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 218.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall 163
com.apple.security.quarantine 3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet 8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement 218.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard 181
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard 181
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver 4.4.0f4
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver 304.9
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDTransport 5
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily 11
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 272.50
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib 525
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface 108.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2 203.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP 2.2.6
com.apple.driver.CoreCaptureResponder 1
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.4.0f4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily 4.4.0f4
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert 1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport 2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 272.50
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 272.50
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d7
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI 1.0.14d1
com.apple.kext.AMDSupport 1.3.6
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl 3.11.31
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink 4.1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC 3.1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController 1.0.14d1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily 2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBAudio 301.52
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily 203.8
com.apple.vecLib.kext 1.2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice 3.7.7
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily 1.8
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily 1.8
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily 1.8
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI 2.6.2
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass 4.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice 3.7.7
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver 1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily 3.7.7
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver 900.4.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice 1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub 1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter 4.1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter 4.1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily 4.1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI 4.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 5.0.6
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family 1100.23
com.apple.driver.corecapture 1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient 1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily 3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily 4.5.8
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily 2.8.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCI 1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties 1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM 2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime 2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily 1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox 300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch 1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore 2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity 1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 414
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily 31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore 28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform 4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily 1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread 1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto 1.0
com.apple.kec.Libm 1
```

### Console

> 9. 11. 2015 8:17:48,195 pm sessionlogoutd[2707]: sessionlogoutd Launched
> 10. 11. 2015 8:17:48,346 pm sessionlogoutd[2707]: DEAD_PROCESS: 1394 console
> 11. 11. 2015 8:17:48,350 pm sessionlogoutd[2707]: Session Logoutd Software Update, waiting for restart.
> 12. 11. 2015 8:17:48,422 pm sessionlogoutd[2707]: ___watchForPIDDeath_block_invoke:47: ERROR: Session Agent exited before sessionlogoutd, exiting.
> 13. 11. 2015 8:17:48,624 pm com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.sessionlogoutd[2707]) Service exited with abnormal code: 3

(date format DD/MM, don't be confused :) )

### EtreCheck Report (the important bit)

> System Launch Daemons:
>   [failed] com.apple.sessionlogoutd.plist

Comment: First thing I'd lose would be Soundflower, but as you appear to have customised your vm at some point & the panic is in the pager, that would be my next guess; try vm_compressor=4

Comment: Hi, got exactly the same. For me solution was to reset PRAM (restart with option + command + P + R down.